# failed to compile Haskell project "helloworld"

Tags: haskell, ghc, cjk

I am a beginner of Haskell and I have downloaded `ghc-8.8.1` from the official site. I tried to compile my first Haskell program with it and failed. Here is my program `helloworld.hs`:

```
main = putStrLn "hello world"
```

Then I compiled it with cmd (Windows 10):

```
ghc --make helloworld
```

And it failed with these words:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( helloworld.hs, helloworld.o )
Linking helloworld.exe ...
C:\Users\蔡XX\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc92756_0\ghc_6.rsp: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

(蔡XX is my name)

Why is it not working? How can I solve this problem?
BTW, my `ghci` is working.

Edit: I created a new user in my computer with English name and copied my `ghc`, and this time it worked. It turns out that this problem was due to the character 蔡 in my path, as the comments said. Thanks guys!

Comment: This looks like an issue with the directory name, which contains non-ASCII characters. Of course, GHC should handle that just fine. One might try running `chcp 65001` before compiling to enable unicode, but I'm unsure about it.

Comment: More specifically, this seems to be a problem with non-ASCII characters _in Windows_. On Linux, GHC does indeed not seem to have any problems with such a directory name. (Likely reason: Windows uses UTF-16 somewhere where Linux and GHC use UTF-8, and the conversion was only tested with ASCII.)

Comment: ...but it could also be that the problem is completely unrelated to the `蔡` character.

Comment: So how can I solve this problem? This path (`C:\Users\蔡XX\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc92756_0\ghc_6.rsp`) has nothing related to where my ghc is (which is at `D:`), so I think this is where `ghc` saves my Haskell projects by default. How can I change this path?

Comment: @Home3: you can create a directory with only ascii characters, create your file there, and compile it there. Perhaps this is a workaround for the issue. Perhaps it is also a good idea to open an issue at the GitHub repository.

Comment: Note that GHC is using that `Temp` directory, even if the file is elesewhere. I guess moving the file won't help. I'd try to define the environment variables `TMP` or `TEMP` or whatever windows uses to prod GHC to use another temporary directory.

Comment: So how can I change my temporary directory? How can I define the environment variables `TMP` or `TEMP`?

Comment: One question per post please. New question? New post.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: _you can create a directory with only ascii characters, create your file there, and compile it there._ The location on the source file does not matter, unfortunately.

Comment: Filled an issue here: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/18332#note_281652